# Problem installing dropbox by line of code on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: dropbox, make

I followed the tutorial on the dropbox site https://www.dropbox.com/help/247 
but when i run "make" shit happens.

```
make[6]: Entering directory '/home/zerbini/Downloads/nautilus-dropbox-1.4.0/data/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps'
make[6]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[6]: Leaving directory '/home/zerbini/Downloads/nautilus-dropbox-1.4.0/data/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps'
make[6]: Entering directory '/home/zerbini/Downloads/nautilus-dropbox-1.4.0/data/icons/hicolor/16x16'
make[6]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.
make[6]: Leaving directory '/home/zerbini/Downloads/nautilus-dropbox-1.4.0/data/icons/hicolor/16x16'
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/zerbini/Downloads/nautilus-dropbox-1.4.0/data/icons/hicolor/16x16'
Making all in 22x22
make[5]: Entering directory '/home/zerbini/Downloads/nautilus-dropbox-1.4.0/data/icons/hicolor/22x22'
Making all in apps
make[6]: Entering directory '/home/zerbini/Downloads/nautilus-dropbox-1.4.0/data/icons/hicolor/22x22/apps'
make[6]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

this happens, and keeps repeating.
How do i solve this?

Comment: These aren't errors, just verbose output of make file.  Is this the whole output? Did you try to continue with `sudo make install`?

Comment: @Michal yes i tried make install but it returns this:                        Makefile:402: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1

Comment: ./configure returned no error?

Comment: @Michal ./configure had no errors, just on make

Comment: Hm, that's strange. Did you try to install it from .deb package? https://www.dropbox.com/install-linux Save the file and run from terminal `sudo dpkg -i "name_of_package.deb"`

Comment: @Michal yes i have installed from .deb package, i also tried in the Ubuntu Software but when i install from there it does not open

Comment: What happens, when you run `dropbox` from terminal?

Comment: @Michal the icon appears in the launchbar it seems normal on shell but the app does not open it closes after a time

Comment: What operating system do you use? Version + bitrate (32 or 64b), please.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04. 32 bit